# How to get column id in elementor hook

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to put Iframe below specific column for which I've putted id `'custom_iframe'` in the elementor editor for that column,

When I echo the `$element->get_ID()`, then auto generated elementor ids are showing, I wanted to get the custom ID which I putted using elementor Edit Column > Advanced > Layout > CSS Id.

How can I do that?

```
function add_custom_script_below_custom_column($element)
{

    if (is_page('careers')) {

        $id = $element->get_ID();
        if ($id == 'custom_iframe') {
            echo '<iframe id="grnhse_iframe" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allow="geolocation" onload="window.scrollTo(0,0)" title="Greenhouse Job Board" src="https://boards.greenhouse.io/embed/job_app?for=rfcareers&amp;token=5746638003" height="100vh"></iframe>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('elementor/frontend/column/after_render', 'add_custom_script_below_custom_column');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using '**get_settings()**', you can access the custom ID that you set using Elementor's editor and check it against your desired ID for placing the iframe.

```
 function add_custom_script_below_custom_column($element)
{
    if (is_page('careers')) {
        $settings = $element->get_settings();  // Retrieve all settings for the column
        $custom_id = $settings['custom_id'];  // Access the custom ID

        if ($custom_id === 'custom_iframe') {
            echo '<iframe id="grnhse_iframe" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allow="geolocation" onload="window.scrollTo(0,0)" title="Greenhouse Job Board" src="https://boards.greenhouse.io/embed/job_app?for=rfcareers&amp;token=5746638003" height="100vh"></iframe>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('elementor/frontend/column/after_render', 'add_custom_script_below_custom_column');
```